# Using Python's multiprocessing.Process class

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

This is a newbie question:

A class is an object, so I can create a class called `pippo()` and inside of this add function and parameter, I don't understand if the functions inside of `pippo` are executed from up to down when I assign `x=pippo()` or I must call them as `x.dosomething()` outside of `pippo`.

Working with Python's multiprocessing package, is it better to define a big function and create the object using the `target` argument in the call to `Process()`, or to create your own process class by inheriting from `Process` class?

Comment: For the first part of your question, if you want a function to be executed when an object is instantiated then you can place a call to it in the classes `__init__` function. You could also you the [property decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). I am not sure what you are asking in the second part. Could you clarify?

Comment: Most often you will invoke class methods via a reference to the object, such as `x.doSomthing()`. You can also use the methods internally as soon as the object is instantiated by having them called from the class `__init__` method.

If you want an object's methods to "run as a process", there are several ways to do it. My personal favorite is to subclass from `Process`.  I explain one way to do this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790816/python-multiprocessing-apply-class-method-to-a-list-of-objects/16202411#16202411

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I often wondered why Python's doc page on [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) only shows the "functional" approach (using `target` parameter). Probably because terse, succinct code snippets are best for illustration purposes. For small tasks that fit in one function, I can see how that is the preferred way, ala:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    print('hello')

p = Process(target=f)
p.start()
p.join()
```

But when you need greater code organization (for complex tasks), making your own class is the way to go:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class P(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        print('hello')

p = P()
p.start()
p.join()
```

Bear in mind that each spawned process is initialized with a copy of the memory footprint of the master process. And that the constructor code (i.e. stuff inside `__init__()`) is executed in the master process -- only code inside `run()` executes in separate processes.

Therefore, if a process (master or spawned) changes it's member variable, the change will not be reflected in other processes. This, of course, is only true for bulit-in types, like `bool`, `string`, `list`, etc. You can however import "special" data structures from `multiprocessing` module which are then transparently shared between processes (see [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).) Or, you can create your own channels of IPC (inter-process communication) such as `multiprocessing.Pipe` and `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Comment: Doesn't multiprocessing require `if __name__ == "__main__"` if you're running on Windows? Just another surprise to note

Comment: If the spawned process changed some of the data types in its class would those changes be visible from the master process?

Comment: @Woody1193, not for built-in data types. But if you use special shared datatypes from the `multiprocessing` module, you will get the desired effect. (I added this explanation to my answer above.)