# Apply a method to a list of objects in parallel using multi-processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have created a class with a number of methods. One of the methods is very time consuming, `my_process`, and I'd like to do that method in parallel. I came across [Python Multiprocessing - apply class method to a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790816/python-multiprocessing-apply-class-method-to-a-list-of-objects) but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem, and what effect it will have on the other methods of my class.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.result = int

    def my_process(self, multiply_by, add_to):
        self.result = self.input * multiply_by
        self._my_sub_process(add_to)
        return self.result

    def _my_sub_process(self, add_to):
        self.result += add_to

list_of_numbers = range(0, 5)
list_of_objects = [MyClass(i) for i in list_of_numbers]
list_of_results = [obj.my_process(100, 1) for obj in list_of_objects] # multi-process this for-loop

print list_of_numbers
print list_of_results

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 101, 201, 301, 401]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm going to go against the grain here, and suggest sticking to the simplest thing that could possibly work ;-)  That is, `Pool.map()`-like functions are ideal for this, but are restricted to passing a single argument.  Rather than make heroic efforts to worm around that, simply write a helper function that only needs a single argument:  a tuple.  Then it's all easy and clear.

Here's a complete program taking that approach, which prints what you want under Python 2, and regardless of OS:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.result = int

    def my_process(self, multiply_by, add_to):
        self.result = self.input * multiply_by
        self._my_sub_process(add_to)
        return self.result

    def _my_sub_process(self, add_to):
        self.result += add_to

import multiprocessing as mp
NUM_CORE = 4  # set to the number of cores you want to use

def worker(arg):
    obj, m, a = arg
    return obj.my_process(m, a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_numbers = range(0, 5)
    list_of_objects = [MyClass(i) for i in list_of_numbers]

    pool = mp.Pool(NUM_CORE)
    list_of_results = pool.map(worker, ((obj, 100, 1) for obj in list_of_objects))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print list_of_numbers
    print list_of_results
```

### A big of magic

I should note there are many advantages to taking the very simple approach I suggest.  Beyond that it "just works" on Pythons 2 and 3, requires no changes to your classes, and is easy to understand, it also plays nice with all of the `Pool` methods.

However, if you have multiple methods you want to run in parallel, it can get a bit annoying to write a tiny worker function for each.  So here's a tiny bit of "magic" to worm around that.  Change `worker()` like so:

```
def worker(arg):
    obj, methname = arg[:2]
    return getattr(obj, methname)(*arg[2:])
```

Now a single worker function suffices for any number of methods, with any number of arguments.  In your specific case, just change one line to match:

```
list_of_results = pool.map(worker, ((obj, "my_process", 100, 1) for obj in list_of_objects))
```

More-or-less obvious generalizations can also cater to methods with keyword arguments.  But, in real life, I *usually* stick to the original suggestion.  At some point catering to generalizations does more harm than good.  Then again, I like obvious things ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't it use however many cores are available if NUM_CORE isn't set?

Comment: Sure.  That's up to you.  However, for a CPU-bound task, it's typical to ask for _fewer_ cores than actually exist, so the OS gets some cycles to run other stuff too.  But, again, that's up to you.  `mp.cpu_count()` returns the number of cores that exist.

Comment: @TimPeters For me this code is slower than the non-parallel version (just a for loop). Do you have any benchmarks?

Comment: The work done per item in this specific code is trivial - no form of multiprocessing can speed it. The overheads of interprocess communications swamp the benefits when work units are so tiny. This answer wasn't aimed at speeding anything, but at illustrating a simple, general _approach_.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is not "huge", I think process oriented is better.
Pool in multiprocessing is suggested.
This is the tutorial -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Then seperate the `add_to` from `my_process` since they are quick and you can wait util the end of the last process.

```
def my_process(input, multiby):
    return xxxx
def add_to(result,a_list):
    xxx
p = Pool(5)
res = []
for i in range(10):
    res.append(p.apply_async(my_process, (i,5)))
p.join()  # wait for the end of the last process
for i in range(10):
    print res[i].get()
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally the easiest way to run the same calculation in parallel is the `map` method of a `multiprocessing.Pool` (or the `as_completed` function from `concurrent.futures` in Python 3).

However, the `map` method applies a function *that only takes one argument* to an iterable of data using multiple processes.

So this function cannot be a normal method, because that requires at least *two* arguments; it must also include `self`! It could be a staticmethod, however. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7017546/1219295) for a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of [Python Multiprocessing - apply class method to a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790816/python-multiprocessing-apply-class-method-to-a-list-of-objects) and your code:

1. add `MyClass object` into `simulation object`

   ```
   class simulation(multiprocessing.Process):
       def __init__(self, id, worker, *args, **kwargs):
           # must call this before anything else
           multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
           self.id = id
           self.worker = worker
           self.args = args
           self.kwargs = kwargs
           sys.stdout.write('[%d] created\n' % (self.id))
   ```
2. run what you want in `run` function

   ```
       def run(self):
           sys.stdout.write('[%d] running ...  process id: %s\n' % (self.id, os.getpid()))
           self.worker.my_process(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
           sys.stdout.write('[%d] completed\n' % (self.id))
   ```

Try this:

```
list_of_numbers = range(0, 5)
list_of_objects = [MyClass(i) for i in list_of_numbers]
list_of_sim = [simulation(id=k, worker=obj, multiply_by=100*k, add_to=10*k) \
    for k, obj in enumerate(list_of_objects)]  

for sim in list_of_sim:
    sim.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't absolutely need to stick with Multiprocessing module then,
it can easily achieved using [concurrents.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) library

here's the example code:

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait

MAX_WORKERS = 20

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.result = int

    def my_process(self, multiply_by, add_to):
        self.result = self.input * multiply_by
        self._my_sub_process(add_to)
        return self.result

    def _my_sub_process(self, add_to):
        self.result += add_to

list_of_numbers = range(0, 5)
list_of_objects = [MyClass(i) for i in list_of_numbers]

With ThreadPoolExecutor(MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
    for obj in list_of_objects:
        executor.submit(obj.my_process, 100, 1).add_done_callback(on_finish)

def on_finish(future):
    result = future.result() # do stuff with your result
```

here executor returns future for every task it submits. keep in mind that if you use `add_done_callback()` finished task from thread returns to the main thread (which would block your **main thread**) if you really want true parallelism then you should wait for future objects separately. here's the code snippet for that.

```
futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
    for objin list_of_objects:
        futures.append(executor.submit(obj.my_process, 100, 1))
wait(futures)

for succeded, failed in futures:
    # work with your result here
    if succeded:
       print (succeeeded.result())
    if failed:
        print (failed.result())
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Keep in mind that on the standard implementation of Python only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. On this implementation threads will not improve CPU-bound performance.

Comment: For CPU-bound tasks you just need to swap the `ThreadPoolExecutor` for a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.  You'll take a small hit as the processes start up, but after that the workers can execute at the same time.  Note that you the data that is returned from the sub-processes needs to be pickle-able.