# Call many object's methods in parallel in python

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I have two classes. One called `algorithm` and the other called `Chain`. In `algorithm`, I create multiple chains, which are going to be a sequence of sampled values. I want to run the sampling in parallel at the chain level.

In other words, the `algorithm` class instantiates n chains and I want to run the `_sample` method, which belongs to the `Chain` class, for each of the chains in parallel within the `algorithm` class.

Below is a sample code that attempts what I would like to do.

I have seen a similar questions here: [Apply a method to a list of objects in parallel using multi-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002766/apply-a-method-to-a-list-of-objects-in-parallel-using-multi-processing), but as shown in the function `_sample_chains_parallel_worker`, this method does not work for my case (I am guessing it is because of the nested class structure).

**Question 1**: Why does this not work for this case?

The method in _`sample_chains_parallel` also does not even run in parallel.

**Question 2**: Why?

**Question 3**: How do I sample each of these chains in parallel?

```
import time
import multiprocessing

class Chain():

    def __init__(self):
        self.thetas = []

    def _sample(self):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.thetas.append(i)

    def clear_thetas(self):
        self.thetas = []

class algorithm():

    def __init__(self, n=3):
        self.n = n
        self.chains = []

    def _init_chains(self):
        for _ in range(self.n):
            self.chains.append(Chain())

    def _sample_chains(self):
        for chain in self.chains:
            chain.clear_thetas()
            chain._sample()

    def _sample_chains_parallel(self):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=self.n)
        for chain in self.chains:
            chain.clear_thetas()
            pool.apply_async(chain._sample())
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def _sample_chains_parallel_worker(self):

        def worker(obj):
            obj._sample()

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=self.n)
        pool.map(worker, self.chains)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()


if __name__=="__main__":
    import time

    alg = algorithm()
    alg._init_chains()

    start = time.time()
    alg._sample_chains()
    end = time.time()
    print "sequential", end - start

    start = time.time()
    alg._sample_chains_parallel()
    end = time.time()
    print "parallel", end - start

    start = time.time()
    alg._sample_chains_parallel_worker()
    end = time.time()
    print "parallel, map and worker", end - start
```

Comment: @Prune I edited the question to make my questions clearer. How dissimilar is this from the question i referenced (link on in my question)?

Comment: I see your issues *much* better now; thanks!  I'm removing my original comment, as I'm worried it could scare off helpers who would otherwise diagnose this much faster than I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `_sample_chains_parallel` you are calling `chain._sample()` instead of just passing the function: `pool.apply_async(chain._sample())`. So you are passing the result as an argument instead of letting `apply_async` calculate it.

But removing `()` won't help you much, because Python 2 cannot pickle instance methods (possible for Python +3.5). It wouldn't raise the error unless you call `get()` on the result objects so don't rejoice if you see low times for this approach, that's because it immidiately quits with an unraised exception.

For the parallel versions you would have to relocate `worker` to the module level and call it `pool.apply_async(worker (chain,))` respectively `pool.map(worker, self.chains)`.

Note that you forgot `clear_thetas()` for `_sample_chains_parallel_worker`. The better solution would be anyway to let let `Chain._sample` take care of calling `self._clear_thetas()`.